# Python PIL getdata() method doesn't return a tuple

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a question about the Python module PIL:

Whenever I call the `getdata()` method on an image, I get something weird returned.

```
from PIL import Image

# Histogram class to get the data
class Histogram:
    def __init__(self, image):
        image.convert("RGB")
        pixel_value_list = list(image.getdata())
        print(pixel_value_list[1])

image = Image.open("lenna.gif")
histogram = Histogram(image)
```

But I do not get a tuple printed to the console, but somehow 45...

Why does the `list(image.getdata())` not return a list with tuples but a list entirely made of integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open a palettized file (like a GIF), and print the list of pixels via `.getdata()`, you'll get a list of indexes into the palette, e.g.:

```
im = Image.open("composplot.gif")
print(list(im.getdata()))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 223, 0, 0, 46, 219, 195, ...]
```

However, if your convert the palettized image to a RGB image, you'll get a list of (r,g,b) tuples. Example:

```
im = Image.open("composplot.gif")
imrgb = im.convert("RGB")
print(list(imrgb.getdata()))
```

Output:

```
[(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (216, 216, 216), (8, 8, 8), (191, 191, 191), (255, 255, 255), ...]
```

Comment: Also, remember that `image.convert("RGB")` returns a *new* image, it doesn't alter the image itself.